# Android post image and display response with ImageView

Tags: android, post, flask, android-volley

I'm trying to

1. send image to server.
2. server handles the image.
3. server returns handled image.
4. Android displays handled image onto ImageView.

I'm not sure how to get image from response (see below Android code)

How can I resolve this?

**Server (python, flask):**

```
@app.route("/comi", methods=['POST'])
def main():
    mi = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(request.files['file'].read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR )
    co = cv2.imread(random.choice(co_list))
    cominame = morph(co, mi, ld, app.static_folder)
    return send_file(cominame, mimetype='image/png')
```

**Android:**

```
    private void POSTImage(String miFilePath){
    final Bitmap miImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(miFilePath);
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Volley works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // ** Handle response **
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> param = new HashMap<>();

            String images = getStringImage(miImage);
            param.put("file", images);
            return param;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap){
    Log.i("MyHitesh",""+bitmap);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
    byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
    String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify you're issue. You are "struggling", but don't say with what. You ask "how can I resolve this", but don't actually ask a question. Read this then edit your post with a clear question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @dominicoder Thanks for your comment and I updated my question.

Comment: Are you saying that you are getting a string response, where the string represents your encoded image, and you need help converting that string to an image?

Comment: @dominicoder  I'm not sure of the type of send_file response. Also curious how to convert that response to image.

Comment: How are you not sure of the response? Isn't this your own code? If you don't know what it is, certainly no one here will. As far as converting the image, assuming it's base 64 encoded, you would use the same approach as you already did to encode the original image. A search for "android base 64 image decoding" should give you lots of options.

Comment: You might not see `send_file` of flask. I'm asking how to handle response from `send_file`. That's a part of api.